# Configuring jack into a microphone input

Tags: pi-2, audio

Is there any way that I can configure the jack on a Raspberry 2 into a microphone input ?
The goal is to gather the sound data from a microphone that I would plug into the jack and save it to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The Pi's 3.5mm jack is output only. If you want to record audio you'll need to use a USB or GPIO based soundcard.

Comment: There is a non-comprehensive list of GPIO sound cards [here](http://elinux.org/index.php?title=RPi_Expansion_Boards#Sound)